# Using CMake install command with Android

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

Is it possible to get the the CMake `install` command to work with android studio cmake ndk builds?  I have the line in my CMakelists.txt used by android but it doesn't seem to do anything when I build the project in android studio.

e.g. something like

```
INSTALL( DIRECTORY ${SOME_DIR} DESTINATION ${INSTALL_DIR} )
```

If not, is there a recommended way to get files copied into the assets folder through cmake with android?

Comment: Did you try it? Did the command in your question work? Were there any errors, or unexpected behavior?

Comment: Updated question with "I have the line in my CMakelists.txt used by android but it doesn't seem to do anything when I build the project in android studio."